# What is the type of parameter used in distanceTo()?

Tags: android, methods, parameters

In the `distanceTo()` method what is the parameter used?I do know that its the location parameter that is used, but my question is that if I am making an app which has to calculate the distance from a particular location say a particular landmark, then what do I enter in the parameter set of the `distanceTo()` function, I do know the latitude and longitude of the place, but the `distanceTo()` function only accepts one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `distanceBetween()` method if you know the latitude and longitude of the place. Take a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29).

Comment: That was helpful,  thanks. But is there a way to use the distanceTo() method for achieving the same result?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure. You can try `location1.distanceTo(location2)` ? But I think `distanceBetween()` is a better way. Why are you so insistent about using `distanceTo()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Method Name: **distanceTo**

---

```
public float distanceTo (Location dest)
```

Since: API Level 1

**Description**

Returns the approximate distance in meters between 
this location and the given location. 
Distance is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.

**Parameters**

> dest  ,*the destination location*

**Returns**

> the approximate distance in meters

---

source Google android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29)

Comment: I know all that. All I want to know is, say I want to measure the distance of a device from a particular place, say with latitude X and longitude Y, so what do I have to put  in place of dest?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936912/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-geopoints) in the 3rd ans he mentioned code how to use distanceTo() method