# Google Map View Projection Zone Listener

Tags: android, listener, projection

There is a google MapView and projection circle zone. if user keep move inside projection circle there should be pop up messagebox so that i need listener and projection implementanion.

I dont know which listener i have to use. ıf you help me i appreciate that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with the distance it works for you I think: [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29)

Yo can implement your listener with a Runnable:

```
  private Handler handler = new Handler();
  public static final int circleCheckingDelay = 1000; // in ms


  private Runnable circleChecker = new Runnable()
  {
      public void run()
      {
          float distance= getDistance(GeoPoint p1, GeoPoint p2);
          if(distance < ...)
          {
            //do something
          }
          handler.removeCallbacks(circleChecker);
          handler.postDelayed(circleChecker, circleCheckingDelay);
      }
  };
```

Add the following functions in your mapActivity:

OnResume:

```
  handler.postDelayed(circleChecker, circleCheckingDelay);
```

OnPause:

```
  handler.removeCallbacks(circleChecker);
```

Check this link too:
[how to find the distance between two geopoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936912/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-geopoints)

for example the function to get the distance:

```
public float getDistance(GeoPoint p1, GeoPoint p2) {
    double lat1 = ((double)p1.getLatitudeE6()) / 1e6;
    double lng1 = ((double)p1.getLongitudeE6()) / 1e6;
    double lat2 = ((double)p2.getLatitudeE6()) / 1e6;
    double lng2 = ((double)p2.getLongitudeE6()) / 1e6;
    float [] dist = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, dist);
    return dist[0];
}
```