# Android - How to get those locations from my database what are within a given distance around my location?

Tags: android, location, distance

I found a lot of solutions to calculate the distance between two locations, just like
[how to find the distance between two geopoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936912/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-geopoints)
or
[Calculating distance between two geographic locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations)
or to be more specific, here's a code for the .distanceTo method:

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");

locationA.setLatitude(pointA.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);
locationA.setLongitude(pointA.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(pointB.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);
locationB.setLongitude(pointB.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);

double distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

If I have a location (let's say "locationA"), and I have a database with POI-location data, and I'm interested in only those, what are around that location "locationA" within a given distance (let's say "distance"), how do I get those?

If I write a method

```
private Location[] poiAroundMe (Location locationA, double distance) {
   // The necessary calculation
   return locationsAroundMeWithinTheGivenDistance[];
}
```

what would be "the necessary calculation"?

I'm pretty sure, that there's no built-in method for that, so I would like to ask for help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a select on your database, to get all the locations which are inside of a square that includes exactly your "distance-circle".

```
SELECT * 
FROM TblLocations 
WHERE longitude < x 
AND longitude > y 
AND latitude < a
AND latitude > b;
```

Put the data in a array, and give it to your poiAroundMe() -Method.
Inside you can check each for the distance to your locationA with a calcualte-method you already know and filter all, which have a smaller distance to your locationA and put them into your locationsAroundMeWithinTheGivenDistance[]

It's not as clean as you perhaps wish, but it will work i think. ;)

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured out, too, that instead of a "distance-circle" I should use a "distance-square". Not as accurate as I first wanted, but hey, it's working. :-) WHERE longitude < myLongitude + distance AND longitude > myLongitude - distance AND latitude < myLatitude + distance AND latitude > myLatitude - distance;